# Cannot use the Carbon Factory class

Tags: php, php-carbon

I cannot execute this example:

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;

class tempCest
{

    public function testCarbon(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $now200=Carbon::now(-8);
        $now200=Carbon::now(8);                                        

        $factory = new Factory([
            'locale' => 'fr_FR',
            'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris'
        ]);

    }


}
```

Error (reported by codeception) is:  [Error] Class 'Factory' not found

Carbon is in my composer file, and the preceeding commands work ok.

```
   "require": {
    "codeception/robo-paracept": "dev-master",
    "codeception/codeception": "^2.4",
    "symfony/yaml": "^3.4",
    "flow/jsonpath": "^0.4",
    "nextbigsoundinc/dash": "^1.0",
"anahkiasen/underscore-php" : "dev-master",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.33"
```

The docs (including the use of factory) can be found here: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: Have you updated composer?

Comment: Is Factory supported in v1.33?  It’s in the Carbon 2 section of the docs.  Worth a check anyway.

Comment: That is probably the problem, I'll check when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

You need to `use` the `Factory` class from Carbon.
So:

```php
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\Factory; // Here is the "inclusion" of Factory.

class tempCest
{

    public function testCarbon(ApiTester $I)
    {
        $now200=Carbon::now(-8);
        $now200=Carbon::now(8);                                        

        $factory = new Factory([
            'locale' => 'fr_FR',
            'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris'
        ]);

    }


}
```